# How can I call a method immediatly after the class is constructed in c#?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have an abstract class called `ReportFunction`. It has a default constructor that should always invokes the method `ValidateAndSetParameters()` after it is constructed.

Here is my abstract class

```
public abstract class ReportFunction
{

    public IList<IReportFilter> Parameters { protected get; set; }
    public ICollection<IReportFilter> ValidParameter { get; protected set; }

    /****
     * 
     * This method should validate parameters if any exists.
     * Then it should add valid parameters to the 'ValidParameter' list
     * 
     */
    public virtual void ValidateAndSetParameters()
    {
        this.ValidParameter = new Collection<IReportFilter>();
    }

    .... I removed irrelevant methods for the sake of simplicity

    public ReportFunction()
    {
        this.ValidateAndSetParameters();
    }

}
```

I completed `ReportFunction` class with the following `Replace` class

```
public class Replace : ReportFunction
{
    public override void ValidateAndSetParameters()
    {
        if (this.Parameters != null && this.Parameters.Count() == 3)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in this.Parameters)
            {
                if (parameter.ReportColumn == null)
                {
                    //Since this is a string function, the filter values should be text, force the filter type to SqlDbType.NVarChar which is the max allowed characters to replace using Replace function 
                    parameter.Type = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                }
                this.ValidParameter.Add(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    public Replace() :base()
    {
    }

    public Replace(IReportFilter stringExpression, string stringPattern, string stringReplacement)
    {
        this.Parameters = new List<IReportFilter>
        {
            stringExpression, 
            new ReportFilter(stringPattern),
            new ReportFilter(stringReplacement)
        };

        this.ValidateAndSetParameters();
    }

}
```

I initialize the `Replace` class one in two ways

```
new Replace
{
    Parameters = new List<IReportFilter>
    {
        new ReportFilter("something to search in"),
        new ReportFilter("something to search for"),
        new ReportFilter("Something to replace with"),
    }
};
```

or like this

```
Replace(new ReportFilter("something to search in"), "something to search for", "Something to replace with");
```

I expect or need to call the method `ValidateAndSetParameters()` **after** the class is constructed and the Parameters property is set. But what seems to be happening is that the `ValidateAndSetParameters()` is called before the initialization. Or for some reason `Parameters` is not getting set during initialization.

How can I ensure that the method `ValidateAndSetParameters()` is called after the class is constructed and the `Parameters` property is set first?

Comment: You would do it in the property `setter` of `public IList<IReportFilter> Parameters { protected get; set; }`

Comment: I'd use a factory pattern. Possibly an abstract factory pattern if you have base classes

Comment: I like both the factory pattern and template method pattern....

Comment: @Liam can you please tell me how would I use factory pattern here? I have read about the factory pattern but not sure how to fit it here http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory

Answer (score 2):

Your second variant should work in general even though virtual method will be called two times first before ctor and then from inside ctor.

```
var replace= new Replace(new ReportFilter("something to search in"), "something to search for", "Something to replace with");
```

Why is it called two times ?
[Do not call overridable methods in constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

so instead of overriding that method you can use local method or just put validation in ctor and remove overriden ValidateAndSetParameters